# Excel 2007 Macro does not work in 2010

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

This macro worked just fine before we updated to windows 7 and Excel 2010.
The macro stops at Activesheet.paste.  All this does is open a file, copy the data and paste it to the first document.  There is more code at the end to close all the open documents.  Thanks, Bob

```
Application.Goto Reference:="R7C14"
Workbooks.Open Filename:="ALSP.xls"
Workbooks("ALSP.xls").Activate
Range("B7:L61").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("R4SP.xls").Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of SELECT and ACTIVATE is cumbersome, you should be able to set variables references to your worksheet(s) and do copy commands directly with no selecting.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, wbREF As Workbook

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set wbREF = Workbooks.Open("ALSP.xls")      'you may want to put the full path here

Range("B7:L61").Copy ws.Range("N7")         'copy to original sheet

wbREF.Close False                           'close the opened workbook, return to ws
```

To paste values, separate the copy/paste to separate commands:

```
Set wbREF = Workbooks.Open("GASP.xls")      'you may want to put the full path here

Range("B7:L61").Copy 
ws.Range("AL7").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues  'copy to original sheet
wbREF.Close False
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. It worked perfectly.  I do have another question now.  One of the documents I need to copy over has formulas and such.  I need it to paste values.  Can you assist?

Comment: I've edited the post above to give the second option to paste values.

Comment: Thank you soo much.  I did have the right code however I did not put it on a separate line.  GREAT HELP.